# Excel: How to change the date column to display only Month of the date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm working on generating a report by month and I'm going to create Graph based on the month values.

Consider I'm having `1000+` records in my excel sheet and there is a column called `created_date` which is containing the values like `11/1/2019  1:34:00 AM`. I'm looking for a function or any solution to convert the `created_date` value to `11` or `11/2019` so I can generate a chart by Month.

> Note: I'm using the online version of Microsoft Excel for this operation.

For Example - I have attached some records below.

*Created_date*

```
11/1/2019 1:34
11/1/2019 0:10
10/31/2019 19:31
10/31/2019 8:32
10/31/2019 3:59
10/31/2019 0:06
10/29/2019 23:48
10/29/2019 23:37
10/29/2019 22:35
10/29/2019 22:33
10/29/2019 22:26
10/29/2019 19:15
10/25/2019 20:44
10/25/2019 3:36
10/5/2019 3:25
10/5/2019 1:52
10/3/2019 0:40
10/2/2019 19:23
10/1/2019 3:56
9/27/2019 4:23
9/27/2019 0:19
9/25/2019 0:46
9/24/2019 22:22
9/24/2019 22:20
9/24/2019 17:12
9/20/2019 20:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your data is in cell A1, input the formula into cell B1 =TEXT(A1,"mm/yyyy"). This wil give you output of 11/2019. If you only want a 2 digit month, change the formula to =TEXT(A1,"mm"). You can then reference your chart to this new column.